# Problem printing iframe Google map within bootstrap visible-print div

Tags: css, google-maps, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, printing

I'm working on a web site that needs a fairly complex print layout. Within one of the printable areas is a Google map - iframe version.

But I can't get the map to print.

I've created a test HTML page containing minimal HTML/CSS/JS to demonstrate the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="idHead">
    <title>iFrame inside .visible-print</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <style media="print">
        .visible-print-block {
            border: 10px solid red !important;
            width: 620px !important;
            height: 470px !important;
            display: block !important;
        }
        .visible-print iframe {
            border: 10px solid blue !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="visible-print visible-print-block">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2418.4013212105515!2d-1.656887048290665!3d52.68884797974762!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zNTLCsDQxJzE5LjkiTiAxwrAzOScxNi45Ilc!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1567617099057!5m2!1sen!2suk" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected results is a blank web page when you view it in the browser, but the print preview (and the print) would show a red bordered area containing the map.

What I get is an empty red bordered area.

I added the blue border to the iframe to show where the iframe should be and to check the iframe is showing.

I've looked through the Bootstrap CSS and can't see how the 'visible-print' 'visible-print-block' could affect the iframe or the Google map.

If I take the iframe out of the container div it appears and prints correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps cannot render on a hidden div. If you need to print this, i suggest you to create another page just to print.